# More informative comparison of objects in C#

Tags: c#, testing, compare

In my C# testing, I often want to compare two objects of the same type (typically an expected object against the actual object), but I want to allow for some flexibility. For example, there may be timestamp fields that I know can't be equal or some fields that I just want to ignore when comparing the objects.

Most importantly, I want to provide an informative message that describes where the two object properties' values differ in order that I can quickly identify what the problem is. For example, a message that says "Source property Name value Fred does not match target property Name value Freda".

The standard Equals and Comparer methods just seem to return ints or Booleans which don't provide enough information for me. At the moment, my object comparison methods return a custom type that has two fields (a boolean and a message), but my thinking is that there must be a more standard way to do this. These days, perhaps a Tuple might be the way to go, but I would welcome suggestions.

Comment: I read through the referenced question and its answers before posting mine, but it doesn't really address quite the same problem. I'm less concerned with performance than I am in getting useful information about where and how the comparison fails. So I need more information to come back than just a boolean or int.

Comment: I think your question is too broad to answer. Perhaps you could propose some sample uses of your hypothetical return type?

Comment: I guess you could use reflection, or just roll your own comparison routines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Comparison" might not be the word for what you're trying to do. That word already has a common meaning in this context. We compare objects for equality, which returns a `boolean` - they are equal or they are not. Or we compare them to see which is greater. That returns an `int` which can indicate that one or the other is greater, or that they are equal. This is helpful when sorting objects.

What you're trying to do is determine specific differences between objects. I wouldn't try to write something generic that handles different types of objects unless you intend for them to be extremely simple. That gets really complicated as you get into properties that return additional complex objects or collections or collections of complex objects. It's not impossible, just rarely worth the effort compared to just writing a method that compares the particular type you want to compare.

Here's a few interfaces and classes that could make the task a little easier and more consistent. But to be honest it's hard to tell what to do with this. And again, it gets complicated if you're dealing with nested complex properties. What happens if two properties both contain lists of some other object, and all the items in those lists are the same except one on each side that have a differing property. Or what if they're all different? In that case how would you describe the "inequality" of the parent objects? It might be useful to know that they are or are not equal, but less so to somehow describe the difference.

```
public interface IInstanceComparer<T>
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyDifference> GetDifferences(T left, T right);
}

public abstract class InstanceComparer<T> : IInstanceComparer<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<PropertyDifference> GetDifferences(T left, T right)
    {
        var result = new List<PropertyDifference>();
        PopulateDifferences(left, right, result);
        return result;
    }

    public abstract void PopulateDifferences(T left, T right, 
       List<PropertyDifference> differences);
}

public class PropertyDifference
{
    public PropertyDifference(string propertyName, string leftValue, 
        string rightValue)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        LeftValue = leftValue;
        RightValue = rightValue;
    }
    public string PropertyName { get; }
    public string LeftValue { get; }
    public string RightValue { get; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int NumberOfLimbs { get; }
    public DateTime Created { get; }
}

public class AnimalDifferenceComparer : InstanceComparer<Animal>
{
    public override void PopulateDifferences(Animal left, Animal right, 
        List<PropertyDifference> differences)
    {
       if(left.Name != right.Name) 
           differences.Add(new PropertyDifference("Name", left.Name, right.Name));
       if(left.NumberOfLimbs!=right.NumberOfLimbs) 
           differences.Add(new PropertyDifference("NumberOfLimbs", 
               left.NumberOfLimbs.ToString(), 
               right.NumberOfLimbs.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer that's closest in spirit to what I currently do. I must admit I was hoping that someone would describe an "off-the-shelf" approach that already exists in C# or standard library that I didn't know about, but maybe that's hoping for too much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use extension methods to do this. For example:

```
public static Extensions
{
    public static void CompareWithExpected(this <type> value, <type> expected)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Property1, value.Property1, "Property1 did not match expected";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Property2, value.Property2, "Property2 did not match expected";
    }
}
```

Then this can be used as follows:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    // Arrange
    ...

    // Act
    ...

    // Assert
    value.CompareWithExpected(expected);
}
```

You could have any number of these extension methods allowing you the flexibility to check only certain values etc.

This also means you do not need to pollute your types with what is essentially test code.